# WebView cookies in a HTTP Request

Tags: android

Is it possible to use the cookies of a WebView in a HTTP Request? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CookieManager is what you are looking for!

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context)
```

Create the manager

```
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync()
```

in Activity.onResume(), and call

```
 CookieSyncManager.getInstance().stopSync()
```

in Activity.onPause().

To get instant sync instead of waiting for the timer to trigger, the host can call

```
 CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync()
```

Note that even sync() happens asynchronously, so don't do it just as your activity is shutting down.

Heres how you might go about using it:

```
// use cookies to remember a logged in status   
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
setContentView(webview);      
webview.loadUrl([MY URL]);
```

[Referenced from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566485/webview-and-cookies-on-android)

EDIT:
If you wanted to do it with a HttpClient, you would need to create an HttpContext.

```
// Create a local instance of cookie store
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

// Create local HTTP context
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
// Bind custom cookie store to the local context
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 

System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

// Pass local context as a parameter
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
```

[Referenced from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587254/how-do-i-manage-cookies-with-httpclient-in-android-and-or-java)

Comment: Mm, can I add them in an DefaultHttpClient?

Comment: I think you don't understand me. I want to use the cookies of my webview IN my http client.  Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Its somewhat of a combination of techniques, check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080761/sharing-cookies-from-webview-with-basichttprequest-on-android