# Android App: How authenticate via web-based login

Tags: android, rest, authentication, android-authenticator

I am writing an Android app that makes calls to a REST Api. The user must be logged in and in order to do so, he must authenticate on the server which in turn redirects to the Identity Provider of my university.

My idea was to let the user log in via the android in-app browser and then extract the session cookie (and csrf, if necessary) into the app's `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` once the user is logged in.

How can I do this? I would also be happy about some helpful links. And secondly, is my way really the way to go?

Comment: if I understood, you want to do is HTTP Basic Authentication, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968416/how-to-do-http-authentication-in-android

Comment: I am not sure.. I need to follow some redirects. Not as important, but I also want to display some information from the login page. I was researching a bit in the meantime and I think this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100086/android-extracting-cookies-after-login-in-webview fits my needs better.

Comment: This page gives you more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080761/sharing-cookies-from-webview-with-basichttprequest-on-android?rq=1, however your question may be marked as duplicated.